# Why do I get the error 'The provided information does not map to an AD object id.' when executing New-AzRoleAssignment using a Service Principal?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-keyvault, azure-rbac

Using Powershell in an Azure DevOps pipeline, I am trying to assign the key vault's principal the role `Storage Account Key Operator Service Role` to a storage account.

**Command Line**

The command line is run after I connected Azure with the service principal:

```
$credentials = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($servicePrincipalApplicationId, $clientSecret)

Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -Credential $credentials -Tenant $tenantId
```

Here is the command line that I execute :

```
New-AzRoleAssignment -ApplicationId $keyVaultServicePrincipalId -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -ResourceName $storageAccountName -ResourceType "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts" -RoleDefinitionName "Storage Account Key Operator Service Role"
```

Where:

- `$keyVaultServicePrincipalId` is the [pre-registered principal ID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/secrets/overview-storage-keys-powershell#service-principal-application-id) for Key Vault. Its value is `cfa8b339-82a2-471a-a3c9-0fc0be7a4093`.
- `$resourceGroupName` is the name of the resource group in which the storage is located. Its value is `accountsmanager-test-global-rg`.
- `$storageAccountName` is the name of my storage account. Its value is `accountsmanagertest`.

**Service Principal**

Here are the permission of the service principal under which the command is run:

[image: Service Principal permissions]

The command is run as a Service Principal that has the Owner role in the subscription:

[image: Owner in Subscription]

The resource group created in that subscription is also owned by that Service Principal:

[image: Owner in Resource Group]

**Question**

When I run the command, I get the following error:

```
New-AzRoleAssignment: The provided information does not map to an AD object id.
```

Why do I get the error `The provided information does not map to an AD object id.` when executing the command `New-AzRoleAssignment`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can also reproduce this on my side, there are two issues.

[image]

1.In your command, the `ResourceType` should be `Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts`, not `Microsoft.Storage/storageAccount`.

2.In the API permission of your AD App related to the service principal used in the DevOps servcie connection, you need to add the *Application permission* `Directory.Read.All` in `Azure Active Directory Graph`, not `Microsoft Graph`.

[image]

[image]

[image]

After a while to take effect, it will work fine.

[image]

Comment: I was avoiding the Legacy permissions, but it works. Great answer :)